# Flutter : Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I can build flutter (3.16.0) on ios (simulator) but can't open it
(android simulator can be installed and used normally)

and I tried delete "ios" file and creating a new one
`flutter run --no-enable-impeller Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode... Running pod install...                                              3.9s Running Xcode build...                                           └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         5.9s Xcode build done.                                           51.3s`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e4kp.png)

I want to know if the bug is in my flutter project ?